# query range on column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help on query where I can do the range query based on Name Column from names.
e.g., as shown in sample data
starting from 'A% to 'C%'
and
from 'a% to 'c%'
and then from 'D%' to 'F%'
and from 'd%' and 'f%'

I need to split Name Column in 2 separate category which is from A to C and from D to F including all names with upper & lower case.

I tried with >=, <= and between, but it didn't help.

[image: Sample Data]

Comment: Explain your question with an example and desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex to achieve that. Try below query

```
select Name,(case when name like '[A-Na-n]%' then 'Category A-N' when name like '[O-Zo-z]%' then 'Category O-Z' end)Category from names where name like '[A-Za-z]%'
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: thanks for your reply, I have added sample data. i replicate your code, but didn't returned any results.

Comment: Sorry, my database context was different. your query helped. Thank you again.